# Geocoder not working in android 2.3.3 and android 3.0

Tags: android, eclipse

public class LocateActivity extends MapActivity {

```
MapView mapView = null;  

Geocoder geocoder = null; 
Drawable drawable = null;

Geocoder gc = null;

final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

String status;
double lat;

double lng;

public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public AutoCompleteTextView filltt;
public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; //

ProgressDialog pDialog;
PlacesList nearPlaces;

List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

GeoPoint geoPoint;
// Map controllers
MapController mc;

double latitude;
double longitude;
OverlayItem overlayitem;

Drawable drawable_user;
Drawable drawablee;

String locnm;

GPSTracker gps;

GooglePlaces googlePlaces;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  



    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());



    filltt = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.geoMap);  
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
    mapView.setClickable(true);  
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    gc = new Geocoder(this);

    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pon);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    filltt.setAdapter(adapter);
    filltt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (count%3 == 1) {
        adapter.clear();
                        GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                                //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                                        task.execute(filltt.getText().toString());
                }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
        });



    // map starting point  
    int lat = (int) (51.678383 * 1000000);  
    int lng = (int) (19.334822 * 1000000);  
    GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);  
    mapView.getController().setZoom(18);  
    mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);  

    final String lattt="23.0666";
    final String loggg="72.6666";

    Button geoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geocodeBtn);  

  //  geoBtn.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Year:</b>2012,<b>Franch</b>"));
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);  

    geoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            try {  

                locnm = filltt.getText().toString();

                if(locnm.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(LocateActivity.this, "Enter Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
               // EditText locale = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);  
                {
                new LoadPlaces().execute();


                String locationName = filltt.getText().toString();  

                Toast.makeText(LocateActivity.this, locationName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               System.out.println("location: "+locationName);


                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(  
                        locationName, 5);  

                System.out.println("first val: " + addressList.get(0));
                System.out.println("Total Result: " + addressList.size());

                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {  
                    int lat = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1e6);  
                    int lng = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1e6);  



                }  
              }  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    });  
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // refresh your views here
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{

    @Override
               // three dots is java for an array of strings
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args)
    {

        Log.d("gottaGo", "doInBackground");

        ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {

            URL googlePlaces = new URL(
            // URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
                    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="+ URLEncoder.encode(args[0].toString(), "UTF-8") +"&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDYnuaL0x_7xGNqrEvYkgEB20_k-b4avOI");
            URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                            //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                System.out.println("Line: "+line);
                }
                            //turn that string into a JSON object
            JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                           //now get the JSON array that's inside that object           
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));
            System.out.println(ja.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                                    //add each entry to our array
                    predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                }
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("YourApp", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("YourApp", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);
        }
        return predictionsArr;
}

//then our post

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
{

    Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());
    //update the adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    //attach the adapter to textview
    filltt.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (String string : result)
    {

        Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute : result = " + string);
        adapter.add(string);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter" + adapter.getCount());

}
```

}

```
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, PlacesList> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LocateActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected PlacesList doInBackground(String... args) {
        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            if(gc.isPresent()){
                  List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(locnm, 1);

                  Address address = list.get(0);

                  lat = address.getLatitude();
                  lng = address.getLongitude();
                }

            System.out.println("Lat Val: " + lat);
            System.out.println("Long Val: " + lng);


            String types = ""; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

            // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
            double radius = 1000; // 1000 meters 

            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(lat,
                    lng, radius, types);

            System.out.println("Places: "+nearPlaces);
          //    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nearPlaces;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * and show the data in UI
     * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
     * thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList file_url) {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        signal.countDown();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                // Get json response status
                status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                            // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);

                            System.out.println("Place Name: " +p.name);



                            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                            System.out.println("ITEM: " + placesListItems.get(0));
                        }

                    }
                }
                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){

                }
                else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                {

                }
                else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                {

                }
                else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                {

                }
                else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        });

         try {
            signal.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),
                (int) (lng * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

                // Map overlay item
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                        place.vicinity);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

}


@Override  
public boolean isLocationDisplayed() {  
    return false;  
}  

@Override  
public boolean isRouteDisplayed() {  
    return false;  
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitByBackKey();

        //moveTaskToBack(false);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
protected void exitByBackKey() {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Do you really want to Exit ?")
    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            filltt.setText("");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            //close();


        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                       }
    })
      .show();

}
```

}

Note: this code run perfectly in android 4.0 but when i test it in android 2.3, it gives me force close error. and throws me error like
Service not available.. and latitude and longtitude values are 0.
what is the solution for that? Please, help me to get out of this.

Comment: Are you running in an emulator? If I remember correctly, there are issues on some API levels.

Comment: please share logcat
what you have set min sdk ver ?

Comment: yes i am running on emulator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    I got the solution.

    package com.example.locatebased;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import org.kxml.*;
    import org.kxml.io.*;
    import org.kxml.kdom.*;
    import org.kxml.parser.*;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class Geocoding
    {
        Hashtable ht=null;
        private boolean time=true;
        private int count=0;
        private String citystreetvalue=null;

         public Geocoding()
         {
             System.out.println("Constructor call...");
             ht=new Hashtable();
         }

    //***************************** Find Address of the latitude Longitude ***********

        public String parseXml(String address)
        {       

            try
            {

                System.out.println("Address is:" + address);
                //URL mUrl = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=tagore%20road%20rajkot&sensor=false");

                URL mUrl = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");

                Log.e("Url",mUrl.toString());
                HttpURLConnection mConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();

                System.out.println("After address add...");
               InputStream is = mConn.getInputStream();
               Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
               XmlParser parser = new XmlParser(reader);
               traverse(parser,"");


               mConn.disconnect();
               is.close();

               System.out.println("Close all connection...");
               if(ht.get("status").toString().equals("OK"))
               {
                System.out.println("result is Ok..." + ht.get("locality").toString() );
                citystreetvalue=ht.get("latitude").toString() + ","+ ht.get("longitude").toString() +","+ht.get("locality").toString();
               }
               else
               {
                System.out.println("result is not Ok...");
                citystreetvalue="InvalidLocation";
               }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }


            System.out.println("before returen statement...");
            return citystreetvalue;

        }    

        public void traverse(XmlParser parser, String indent ) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("in Traverse method....");

        boolean leave = false;
        String title = new String();
        String desc = new String();

        do
        {
        ParseEvent event = parser.read ();
        ParseEvent pe;
        switch (event.getType())
        {
         // For example, <title>
         case Xml.START_TAG:
         // see API doc of StartTag for more access methods
         // Pick up Title for display
         if ("status".equals(event.getName()))
         {
                    pe = parser.read();
                    title = pe.getText();
                    ht.put("status",title); 
         }
             if(count<2)
             {
             if ("lat".equals(event.getName()))
                {

                    pe = parser.read();
                    title = pe.getText();
                    ht.put("latitude",title);
                    count=count+1;

                }
              if ("lng".equals(event.getName()))
              {
                    pe = parser.read();
                    desc = pe.getText();
                    ht.put("longitude",desc);
                    count=count+1;

              }
             }

          if ("long_name".equals(event.getName()))
            {

                pe = parser.read();
                title = pe.getText();

            }

          if ("type".equals(event.getName()))
          {
                pe = parser.read();
                            desc = pe.getText();

                            if(desc.equals("route"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("street is:" + title);
                                ht.put("street",title);
                            }
          }  
         if("formatted_address".equals(event.getName()))
         {

                  if(time)
                  {
                            pe = parser.read();
                            title = pe.getText();
                            ht.put("address",title);
                            time=false;
                  }

         }

              ht.put(desc,title);

          traverse(parser,"") ; // recursion call for each <tag></tag>
          break;
          // For example </title?
         case Xml.END_TAG:
          leave = true;
          break;
          // For example </rss>
         case Xml.END_DOCUMENT:
          leave = true;
          break;
          // For example, the text between tags
         case Xml.TEXT:
          break;
         case Xml.WHITESPACE:
          break;
          default:
          }

          } while( !leave );

         }

    }


now add below code in mainactivity class:

geocoding=new Geocoding();

locnm=locnm.replace(" ","%20");
String citystreetvalue=geocoding.parseXml(locnm);    
System.out.println("string is:" + citystreetvalue);

if(citystreetvalue.equals("InvalidLocation"))
{
    }else
    {                               
        String citystreetval[]=Split(citystreetvalue, ",");     

            String latstreet=citystreetval[2];
            nlatitude=citystreetval[0];
            nlongitude=citystreetval[1];
    }
```

Comment: sure, geocoder is not working in some devices thats why i used this code rather than geocoder. this code is manually take places not using geocoder methods.